# Mapping ExpandoObject to another object type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am working on a helper method that maps properties from an `ExpandoObject` to a user supplied object and was wondering if the code could be cleaned up or made any more efficient. It currently has the correct behaviour from a simple test.

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static void Map<T>(ExpandoObject source, T destination)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = source;
        var type = destination.GetType();

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var lower = prop.Name.ToLower();
            var key = dict.Keys.SingleOrDefault(k => k.ToLower() == lower);

            if (key != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(destination, dict[key], null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full test can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/844736). There is currently no type checking. Would this be next to add?

Comment: If the ExpandoObject's are coming from JSON deserialization, might be simpler if you instead convert to `JObject`s. As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30060974/199364).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've come up with a few changes that should actually speed it up.

```
// By using a generic class we can take advantage
// of the fact that .NET will create a new generic type
// for each type T. This allows us to avoid creating
// a dictionary of Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>
// for each type T. We also avoid the need for the 
// lock statement with every call to Map.
public static class Mapper<T>
    // We can only use reference types
    where T : class
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _propertyMap;

    static Mapper()
    {
        // At this point we can convert each
        // property name to lower case so we avoid 
        // creating a new string more than once.
        _propertyMap = 
            typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary(
                p => p.Name.ToLower(), 
                p => p
            );
    }

    public static void Map(ExpandoObject source, T destination)
    {
        // Might as well take care of null references early.
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (destination == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");

        // By iterating the KeyValuePair<string, object> of
        // source we can avoid manually searching the keys of
        // source as we see in your original code.
        foreach (var kv in source)
        {
            PropertyInfo p;
            if (_propertyMap.TryGetValue(kv.Key.ToLower(), out p))
            {
                var propType = p.PropertyType;
                if (kv.Value == null)
                {
                    if (!propType.IsByRef && propType.Name != "Nullable`1")
                    {
                        // Throw if type is a value type 
                        // but not Nullable<>
                        throw new ArgumentException("not nullable");
                    }
                }
                else if (kv.Value.GetType() != propType)
                {
                    // You could make this a bit less strict 
                    // but I don't recommend it.
                    throw new ArgumentException("type mismatch");
                }
                p.SetValue(destination, kv.Value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd advise you to check out Fasterflect (fasterflect.codeplex.com), which is a library to make reflection tasks easier (through an abstraction over the classic reflection API) and much faster (using dynamic code generation). Also worth mentioning is AutoMapper, which is a library dedicated just to the task of mapping between objects.

Comment: May be ok *for now* but needs more work to handle nested types.

Comment: Be aware that this solution breaks on polymorphism. Suppose T is abstract and you provide an instance of V (V : T) to the mapper of type T, the properties declared at V are not mapped. Is this as designed?

Answer (score 4):

#### Review

- Generic type definition `T` is redundant.
- Looping the `ExpandoObject` is better optimized then looping the destination's properties, because you get the items as key-value pair in a single pass.
- Fetch only publicly accessible setter properties to avoid nasty exceptions on `property.SetValue`.
- Don't be too strict on matching the source and destination's types. Take advantage of the built-in type converter API `Convert.ChangeType`.

#### Proposed Alternative

`TypeExtension` allows for a changing an instance's type.

```
public static class TypeExtension
{
    public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
    {
        type = type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        return type.IsGenericType 
            && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
    }

    public static bool IsNullAssignable(this Type type)
    {
        type = type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        return type.IsNullable() || !type.IsValueType;
    }

    public static object ChangeType(this Type type, object instance)
    {
        type = type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        if (instance == null)
        {
            if (!type.IsNullAssignable())
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException($"{type.FullName} is not null-assignable");
            }
            return null;
        }
        if (type.IsNullable())
        {
            type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        }
        return Convert.ChangeType(instance, type);
    }
}
```

`Mapper` could be optimized, made more robust and better suited to map between different types.

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static void Map(ExpandoObject source, object destination)
    {
        source = source ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        destination = destination ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));

        string normalizeName(string name) => name.ToLowerInvariant();

        IDictionary<string, object> dict = source;
        var type = destination.GetType();

        var setters = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.CanWrite && p.GetSetMethod() != null)
            .ToDictionary(p => normalizeName(p.Name));

        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            if (setters.TryGetValue(normalizeName(item.Key), out var setter))
            {
                var value = setter.PropertyType.ChangeType(item.Value);
                setter.SetValue(destination, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
public class Point
{
    public int? X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic source = new ExpandoObject();
    source.X = 0;
    source.Y = 0m;

    var destination = new Point
    {
        X = 1,
        Y = 1d
    };

    Mapper.Map(source, destination);

    Console.WriteLine(destination.X);
    Console.WriteLine(destination.Y);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: My gut tells me that this is a xy-problem becuase I cannot think of any reasonable use-case where one would want to use such mapping. OP is probably parsing json into `dynamic` instead of `T` thus they need to _fix_ that with this mapper.

Comment: @t3chb0t I can see a use case in WPF when binding a view to an ExpandoObject and mapping further to some DTO. The ExpandoObject can be usefull for a table with a dynamic configurable set of columns.

Comment: @TomBell do you remember what you needed this for?

Comment: I'm answering this question because I feel the accepted answer has a major flaw using the properties of `T`. The instance can be of a derived type, breaking the mapping.

Comment: maybe... but the question is where the `ExpandoObject` is comming from? This is not something you use on a daily basis and not at all for mapping. This is super suspicious.

Comment: sure, the review is fine, +1 as always ;-P but I'm curious about the real use case...

Comment: @t3chb0t - could be from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, where destination is a list of different object types, to be determined by examining some property in each ExpandoObject. As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30060974/199364). Note that a cleaner solution was obtained by converting to `JObject`s instead of `ExpandoObject`s.